# MySQL: return top 16 results in random order

Tags: mysql, random

I am trying to query my database to return, say, the top 16 ordered results (ordered by a field called rank) but in a random order.

I can do this easily by shuffling the returned (and ordered) 16 results using php to adjust the array that php will use. I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this directly in the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
select * from 
(
    select * from your_table 
    order by rank
    limit 16
) x
order by rand()
```

Comment: Wont this always return the same 16 results based on the index used by the query?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: The OP wants the top 16 values (by `rank`) and then shuffle those, this solution does exactly that.

Comment: @muistooshort I disagree - if there are 32 results with the same rank then the same 16 will be returned each time especially if an index on rank is used because the rand() is being applied after the limit clause

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Ah, I see what you mean, you could add a secondary sort key to the inner query for that. Assuming of course that the `rank` values aren't unique, I'd assume that they were unique (or poorly named).